# Using PHP generated images in Discord attachment via link

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to upload an image from a link via my Discord bot. The image is generated with PHP using `Image Processing and Generation` and is outputted in png format.

Although when I try and attach the image to my bots message like this it uploads a random file which I believe is the code behind the png.

```
message.channel.send({files: ["https://banlister.com/profiling/profile.php?id=76561198153846406"]});
```

I have given this a google and spent a bit of time trying to come up with other ways around this but I'm not much a fan of downloading the image each time so I thought I might be able to get some assistance here?

When I tried this with an imgur link it worked also when I linked a local image: [image: example]

I had the impression this would only be possible by downloading the image each time although I thought that I might just as well ask experts just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot sends the image as `profile.php`becuase of the url going to `profile.php`, so you need to specify the format. For example you can do:

```
message.channel.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'https://banlister.com/profiling/profile.php?id=76561198153846406',
    name: 'profile.png'
  }]
})
```

Comment: Oh, awesome. I never remember seeing anything remotely close to that xD Possibly I wasn't looking hard enough. Thanks for your help and hopefully this can clear things up for anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Its in the Docs as one of the examples, there are like 3 or more ways how to send a file.